# SqlConnection is null but why?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to connect to my `GuvenliBilgisayarim` database. But `baglanti` is null - why ?

My code is:

```
SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DILEKZ\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GuvenliBilgisayarim;Integrated Security=True");

private void btn_giris_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    baglanti.Open();
    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select * from Login where kullanici_adi='" + txt_kulAdi.Text + " and kullanici_sifre=" + txt_sifre.Text +"',baglanti");
    komut.Connection = baglanti;

    SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Rapor rpr = new Rapor();
        rpr.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış");
    }

    dr.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that a `NullReferenceException` is thrown on the call to `Open`?

Comment: Yes, I call  and the problem solved. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `SqlCommand`'s `Text` is invalid. The correct is (notice to the quotes `'"`):

```
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select * from Login where kullanici_adi='" + txt_kulAdi.Text + "'" +
                        " and kullanici_sifre='" + txt_sifre.Text + "'",baglanti);
```

However this kind of string concatenation is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead. Something like this:

```
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select * from Login where kullanici_adi=@kulAdi" +
                        " and kullanici_sifre=@sifre",baglanti);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kulAdi",txt_kulAdi.Text);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifre",txt_sifre.Text);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
komut.Parameters.Add("@kulAdi", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_kulAdi.Text;
```

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then the description of your problem in both your title and your post is completely inaccurate.